# Is it necessary for $P(K, t) - P(K + s, t) \geq se^{-rt}$ to hold?

Tags: options, option-pricing, put-call-parity

Let $P(K, t)$ be a put option with strike price $K$ and expiration time $t$. Let $s > 0$.  Is it necessarily true that the inequality

$$P(K, t) - P(K + s, t) \geq se^{-rt}$$

holds? I know that for a call option $C(K, t)$, it can be shown that the inequality $C(K, t) - C(K + s, t) \leq se^{-rt}$ must hold, otherwise there is an arbitrage. In particular, this arbitrage can be obtained by selling a call option with strike price $K$ and exercise time $t$, buying a $C(K + s, t)$ call option, and putting the remaining $C(K, t) - C(K + s, t) \geq se^{-rt}$ in a bank.

So, I was wondering whether there is a similar justification for the inequality I mentioned above to hold.

Comment: No, why? If the put is enough out of the money both puts and the difference will be close enough to zero to make the inequality false.

Comment: Apply the Put Call Parity to the inequality about Calls and see what you get for Puts.